# When a Phantom Knight's Trap is Special Summoned back as a monster, and then is sent to the GY, is it still treated as a monster?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Some Phantom Knight's Card have an Effect that says you can special summon it as a monster (This card is not treated as a trap). When it is destroyed, is it a monster or trap in the GY? (For example, could I use Monster Reborn on it?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: [Trap Monster - Fandom.com](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Trap_Monster)

> ...and can in some cases be used offensively as well. Also, **because they don't count as monsters while in a player's Deck or Graveyard**, some effects might work on them as a Trap Card- ...

A trap monster is only treated as a monster whilst it occupys a monster zone. When it's sent to the graveyard it is reverted back to being treated as a trap.